# Unable to set certificate and keystore details in php curl

Tags: php, apache, curl

I have the following code in curl to authenticate the user.

```
<?php
    $url='https://mysite';
       echo "url -->$url" . "\n";
    $credentials=array('uid'=>'111','password'=>'222');
       print_r($credentials); echo "\n";
    $headers=array('contentType:application/json','MY-API-Key:#$@SDsfsdfsdfsdfsfsf334234');
       print_r($headers); echo "\n";
    $keyFile=file_get_contents( "java.keystore.file");
//     echo "keyFile -->$keyFile" . "\n";
    $certFile = file_get_contents( "cert.pem");
//     echo "certFile -->$certFile" . "\n";
    $keyPass="33333";//key to decrypt keystore file
       echo "keyPass -->$keyPass" . "\n";
    //Start Curl process
    $handle=curl_init();
    if(FALSE==$handle)
       echo "Unable to create Url Object" . "\n";
    else
       echo "Able to create Url Object" . "\n";

    $val=curl_setopt($handle,CURLOPT_URL,$url); 
        if(false==$val)
          echo "Error 1";
    $val=curl_setopt($handle,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headers);   
        if(false==$val)
          echo "Error 2";
    $val=curl_setopt($handle,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);   
        if(false==$val)
          echo "Error 2";
    $val=curl_setopt($handle,CURLOPT_POST, true);   
        if(false==$val)
          echo "Error 4";
    $val=curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $credentials); 
        if(false==$val)
          echo "Error 5";
    $val=curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_SSLKEY, $keyFile);
        if(false==$val)
          echo "Error 6";
//    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_SSLKEYPASSWD, $keyPass);
     $val=curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, $certFile);
        if(false==$val)
          echo "Error 7";
    $val= curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_SSLCERTPASSWD, $keyPass);
        if(false==$val)
          echo "Error 8";
     //  echo "handle -->$handle" . "\n";
    print_r($handle);

    $response=curl_exec($handle);
       echo "response -->$response" . "\n";

    $status_code=curl_getinfo($handle, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
       echo "status code --> $status_code" . "\n";
       curl_close($handle); 

?>
```

In the above code I need to set custom headers.
But I am receiving $response as null and $status_code as 0. please let know whats wrong with the code. The key store file that I have are for java and andriod. Do we need any specific type of file as per the OS. I am trying it on Windows 7 + Wamp(Apache2) but once test is done locally then need to move on Linux 2.6.32-38-server with Apache2.

Please suggest....

Hi, I was able to make the request to my server with following code

```
$headers=array('contentType:application/json','MY-API-Key:ASDASDADADADASDASDASDASDASDASD','Accept-Language:null');                     

    curl_setopt_array($handle, array(
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => true,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 2,
    CURLOPT_VERBOSE => true,
    CURLOPT_HEADER => true,
    CURLOPT_CAINFO => 'C:\wamp\www\my.pem',
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers,
    CURLOPT_USERPWD => base64_encode("uname:pswd"),
    //CURLOPT_SSLCERT => 'C:\wamp\www\my.pem',
    //CURLOPT_SSLKEY => 'C:\wamp\www\my-publickey.keystore',
    CURLOPT_SSLCERTPASSWD => $keyPass,
    CURLOPT_SSLKEYPASSWD => $keyPass,
    CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH => CURLAUTH_BASIC,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => false,
              But when I sent this request to server, it responds back with        HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1 Content-Type: application/json Content-Length: 35 Date: Sat, 21 Dec 2013 13:39:22 GMT Connection: close {"errorCode":"0","errorMessage":""}success while loading page: 1header_size-->173 header --->1 body---"":                                If I make this request from RestClient then I am getting proper response                                                                    



   Status Code: 200 OK
    Content-Encoding: gzip
    Content-Length: 134
    Content-Type: application/json
    Date: Sat, 21 Dec 2013 13:27:51 GMT
    Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
```

I would like to know what needs to be set from my end to get this proper response. I am getting some parameters correctly as follows.
E.g. Server:,Content-Type:,Content-Length:  Date:
Then what could be the reason other parameters are not coming....some inputs would be appriciated...

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add two cURL options and see what happens then:

```
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

[This link](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/stuck-with-php-curl-and-ssl-certificates-322684/#post1640381) says you have to provide the file path for the certificate. Not the content of the file.

Also the [Curl's setopt manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) says its [CURLOPT_SSLKEY -- The name of a file containing a private SSL key]

Comment: I have improved the question and added my inputs. pls see above.

Comment: if you use CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true, it will return you the response content.